# How ensure a clean stacking of several dynamic UIView with Autolayout

Tags: ios, dynamic, uiview, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

Several times, I need to stack views which height that expect to change.

I code this https://github.com/damienromito/UIView-AutoYPositioning

[stack dynamic views http://romito.fr/public/images/UIView+AutoYPositioning.jpg](http://romito.fr/public/images/UIView+AutoYPositioning.jpg)

But I think a best solution with NSLayoutConstraint.
Someone knows?

**EDIT**

Solution programmatically with autolayout:

```
UIView *one = [[UIView alloc]init];
one.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
one.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
[self.view addSubview:one];

UIView *two = [[UIView alloc]init];
two.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
two.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
[self.view addSubview:two];

UIView *three = [[UIView alloc]init];
three.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
three.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
[self.view addSubview:three];

NSDictionary *metrics = @{@"height":@50.0};
NSDictionary *views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(one,two,three);

[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint
                           constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|-[one]-|"
                           options: 0
                           metrics:metrics
                           views:views]];


[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint
                           constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-[one]-[two(300)]-[three(100)]-|"
                           options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllLeft | NSLayoutFormatAlignAllRight
                           metrics:metrics
                           views:views]];
```

Refer you to this tutorial (http://commandshift.co.uk/blog/2013/01/31/visual-format-language-for-autolayout/) as explanation

Comment: You can solve this with auto layout, which requires you to stop thinking about rects and start thinking in relations. In you example, you would need to tell autolayout that where each view should be in relation to other views, and set the size constraint based on the size of the content.

Comment: Yes, I just learned all about this with this awesome tutorial http://commandshift.co.uk/blog/2013/01/31/visual-format-language-for-autolayout/. The main thing to know is, in an autolayout world, "initWithFrame": is no more! Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution programmatically with autolayout:

```
UIView *one = [[UIView alloc]init];
one.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
one.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
[self.view addSubview:one];

UIView *two = [[UIView alloc]init];
two.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
two.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
[self.view addSubview:two];

UIView *three = [[UIView alloc]init];
three.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
three.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
[self.view addSubview:three];

NSDictionary *metrics = @{@"height":@50.0};
NSDictionary *views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(one,two,three);

[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint
                           constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|-[one]-|"
                           options: 0
                           metrics:metrics
                           views:views]];


[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint
                           constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-[one]-[two(300)]-[three(100)]-|"
                           options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllLeft | NSLayoutFormatAlignAllRight
                           metrics:metrics
                           views:views]];
```

Refer you to this tutorial (http://commandshift.co.uk/blog/2013/01/31/visual-format-language-for-autolayout/) as explanation

To help me, I developed a Category for UIView : https://github.com/damienromito/UIView-UpdateAutoLayoutConstraints (able to hide/show autolayout view)

Answer (score 1):

Here is some tutorials on auto layout.
[Raywenderlinch-1](http://www.raywenderlich.com/20881/beginning-auto-layout-part-1-of-2), [Raywenderlinch-2](http://www.raywenderlich.com/20897/beginning-auto-layout-part-2-of-2),